# Mathematical questions on BiologySE

Tags: discussion

I am a third years Maths undergrad student and I am doing a module in Population Dynamics, which contains a lot of mathematical models in Biology. Would asking questions on BiologySE be

a) Allowed

b) Useful

By allowed, I mean will these questions come under the rules and regs for asking questions on here. I know that if there is some pure maths thing to do, I will ask it on Maths SE but if it was more along the lines of the actual model and how it works and solving questions on it, then would I be able to ask it here?

By useful, I mean is there a fair few people who would genuinely be able to help me with this mathematical aspect. I understand there will be plenty of brilliant biologists who understand fields of Biology I didn't even know existed, but for me personally, I would need help from "mathematical biologists". Are there many here?

EDIT: Regarding my models, I look at things like Verhulst Model, Lotka-Volterra-Gausse model,  Hassell model. I do phase plane analysis, logistic maps, variety of discrete time and continuous time analysis, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about mathematical models of biological systems would be on-topic. As for how many users can help you with those, only one way to find out. Just ask the questions and see what kind of answers you get.

Comment: @Kaish There is a continuum along the biology <--> math axis. Questions closer to biology are likely to get answers, whereas those closer to math are less likely. The only way to find out where the community falls on that axis is to ask the question. If it's not answered now, in the future someone may be able to. Also, feel free to publicize the question(s) anywhere that you think interested people might be.

Comment: @kmm Can I ask the same question on the Maths site aswell, just inc ase? Or will that clog up the servers or something?

Comment: Cross-posting is not encouraged. See what happens here first, and we can see about migrating it there later if math.SE is interested.

Comment: @Kaish so kmm is correct -- however, if the *information sought* in each question were different (but the questions were related) then you could ask on both sites. For example: if you wanted to ask about the mathematical method on Math, but ask about the biological theory here, you could feasibly ask the same question on both sites. That said, **posting the same question on both sites is discouraged**.

Comment: you can ask as long as the question is about the **formulation** of the mathematical model of biological situations.. Asking questions about phase planes or stability analysis wont be too fruitful if you ask them here..